# React useMemo doesn't get the most updated state of an array of objects after state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm updating a `useState` array of objects. when I update one of the object's fields (snackbarType) to `'success'` I invoke a `useMemo` hook that should have the latest reference for the array of objects, but it doesn't, I still see it as `'uploading'`.

why is the `useMemo` function not invoked with the last changed array of objects?

the `useMemo` function:

```
const snackbars = useMemo<ProcessSnackbarProps[]>(() => {
    return asyncProcesses
      .filter((process) => !process.isOpenInDialog || displayAsSnackbarList.includes(process.processType))
      .map((process) => {
        const {
          name,
          progress,
          snackbarType,
          snackbarAction,
          processType,
          isActive,
          data: {
            isInactive,
            integrationName,
          },
        } = process;

        console.log('<<<type', process, process.snackbarType, snackbarType);

        return {
          type: snackbarType,
          message: name,
          status: dictionary.snackbar.statusText(snackbarType, processType, progress, isInactive),
          progress: progress,
          onClose: () => removeAsyncProcess(processType),
          integrationName: integrationName,
          isActive: isActive,
          ...snackbarAction,
        };
      });
  }, [asyncProcesses, displayAsSnackbarList, dictionary, removeAsyncProcess]);
```

checking and updating function:

```
const newAsyncProcesses: AsyncProcess[] = [ ...asyncProcesses ];

...

asyncProcesses.forEach(async (process, i) => {
...
const newProcess = await checkUploadCsvProcess(
          process as AsyncProcessCsvUpload,
          {
            actionName: dictionary.review,
            actionOnClick: () => {
              navigate(routes.linkedAccounting);
              setIsOpenInDialog(AsyncProcessType.CsvUpload, true);
            },
          },
        );

...

newAsyncProcesses.splice(i, 1, newProcess);
})

setAsyncProcesses(newAsyncProcesses);
```

changing object function:

```
export const checkUploadCsvProcess = async (
  process: AsyncProcessCsvUpload,
  reviewAction: {
    actionName: string,
    actionOnClick: () => void
  },
): Promise<AsyncProcessCsvUpload | undefined> => {
  try {
    const integration = await integrationsClient.getIntegration(process.data.integrationId);
    const { logs, status } = integration;

    if (status === IntegrationStatus.UPLOAD) {
      process.isActive = true;
      process.progress = Math.round((logs?.info?.progress || 0) / (logs?.info?.transactionCount || 1) * 100);
    }
    else if (status === IntegrationStatus.ERROR) {
      process.isActive = false;
      process.snackbarType = 'error';
      delete process.progress;
      process.snackbarAction = reviewAction;
      process.data.errors = logs?.error || {};
    }
    else {
      process.isActive = false;
      process.snackbarType = 'success';
      delete process.progress;
      process.snackbarAction = reviewAction;
    }

    process.timesChecked++;
    return process;
  }
  catch (error) {
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: `asyncProcesses.forEach(async`  Are you sending the result of this to `Promise.all`, as this will not wait, and `setAsyncProcesses(newAsyncProcesses);` is going to get called before while these promises are still pending.

Comment: Doing ->  `Promise.all(asyncProcesses.map(......)).then(async () => setAsyncProcesses(newAsyncProcesses))` is likely what your after.  This will then make sure all your promises are complete before calling the `setState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to remember when using promises, even when using `async / await`.

`asyncProcesses.forEach(async (process, i) => {`

Array functions like `map` / `forEach` etc are all `sync`, so any `async` code placed in the callbacks will all be executed at once, and `forEach` won't be waiting for these promises to finish.

But what you can do here is use `map`, this will then put them into an `array` of promises, that you can then use `Promise.all` to wait for them to all complete.

eg.

`Promise.all(asyncProcesses.map(......)).then(async () => setAsyncProcesses(newAsyncProcesses))`

By doing the above, the `setAsyncProcesses` is then only called when all the promises have been completed.